# MySQL charset for users table

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I'm building a user table in MySQL using utf8_general_ci as the charset.

1-)using this charset two users named one Bob and another bob will look the same one right? i don't know it this may cause some problems or if it's better to avoid username to be egual but  one uppercase and the other one lowercase

2-) in many sites i've noticed they accept only username with letters form a to z and they don't accept Chinese, Cyrillic or others type of letters. There is a reason for that? my app will be open for users from the whole world althought it ma be translated only in some languages

Answer (score 1):

1. `CI` in `utf8_general_ci` means case-insensitive, so `Bob` and `bob` are the same (updated).
2. In my opinion, I think MySQL have some functions that only support English well (e.g:`SOUNDEX()`).

Therefore, if they accept Chinese and other language like Japanese, Korean,Cyrillic they may deal with searching problem.

Or if their existing db uses latin1, their database cannot stores Unicode correctly because Unicode require 3-bytes while latin1 has just single-byte.

Comment: I think you `misspelled` - case-insensitive, so Bob and bob are SAME. I created primary key for char field with utf8_general_ci and it says `duplicate value`

Comment: so i should use latin1... well if the user use the app these means he know a it of english but i would preferr to let theuser choose... for example twitter accepts also arabyc chars

Comment: i may also use only a-z + numbers but for example a chinese user can type only chinese chars or also latin's ones?

Comment: @MatteoPagliazzi they can type only latin (a->z + some characters) see more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1

Answer (score 1):

1) They're not different.

2) As my experience in my language, we never let user enter some words because we will have problems in finding the exact record. Example: `ی` is a Persian word but in Arabic we have this word again but with two dots under it. See, this is a problem that may occur in the searching because some keyboards enter different `ی`s!

Hope this help you.

Comment: i may also use only a-z + numbers but for example a chinese user can type only chinese chars or also latin's ones?

Comment: Yes, every thing is possible. But I try to limit users to entering a correct range of characters in utf, more English. You can sanitize it by RegEx of course.

Comment: thanks but i have no idea of which chars can cause problems and which not... where can i find them?

Comment: I think, It's a result of experience, I don't know what characters exactly are the cause. They can be different in every language.